# HTML NSString producing different values? 

Tags: html, xcode, ftp, nsstring, youtube

I have working, this string:

```
NSString* embedHTML1 = @"\<html><head>\<style type=\"text/css\">\body {\background-color:     transparent;\color: white;\}\</style>\</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/leqL1QENRTI?version=3&amp;hl=en_US1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \width=\"287\" height=\"125\"></embed>\</body></html>";
```

Which when placed into a UIWebView works fine as an embedded youtube clip.

However, i have an FTP server, when i download the **exact same string** from the server and place it in a NSString like so:

```
NSString* embedHTML1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [link objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + startIndex]];
NSLog(@"%@", embedHTML1);

[clip1 loadHTMLString:embedHTML1 baseURL:nil];
```

*Above is basically the string stored in the array. To prove that is the output of that NSLog in the code above.*

All i get is a UIWebview which is a white screen which starts with "///" and ends with "/" at the bottom

[image: Image showing contents of the array]

What am i doing wrong? I would appreciate your help i have no idea what to do now. Is there something I'm missing with the string?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the characters when you download the string from your server, remove the backslashes.

This code will log the html string without backslashes:

```
NSString *htmlString = NSString* embedHTML1 = @"\<html><head>\<style type=\"text/css\">\body {\background-color:     transparent;\color: white;\}\</style>\</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/leqL1QENRTI?version=3&amp;hl=en_US1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \width=\"287\" height=\"125\"></embed>\</body></html>";
NSLog(@"%@", htmlString);
```

Comment: You still need to escape the embedded double quotes I think

Comment: Nope, no you don't. They only need escaping when you declare a string inline, downloaded strings should be the exact format you want to display. Unless of course they need escaping in the format they are downloaded (e.g. JSON).

Comment: *smacks forehead* - of course!  I was looking at the code frag and thought you were suggesting removing the backslashes from the literal.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah I see, I was just trying to show that the backslashes aren't actually part of the HTML, as the `NSLog()` statement in my fragment will print it without them.

Comment: he was right i took away the escapes. Must of had something to do wit the way the string was stored on the server must of interpreted the escaped differently.